# How to resolve 'undefined symbol: ap_log_error' in mod_security2.so?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have an UBUNTU box and I recently upgraded to apache

```
apachectl -v
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.20 (Ubuntu)

but when I try to start Apache I get this error:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod-security.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_security2.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_security2.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_error
>   Action 'configtest' failed.
>   The Apache error log may have more information.
>      ...fail!

Have you ever seen this kind of error message and what can I do make it work?

Comment: I resolved it by removing apache and then reinstalling it.